# regex line start in character set

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I want to search for a 'b' that occurs either at start of line or followed by 'a'.

Why doesn't `re.match('[\^a]b','b')` match while `re.match('^b','b')` does?

**Update:** I realised I should have been using `search` instead of `match`. I want it to be a positive for things like 'b', 'cab', 'ab', 'bc', and 'abd'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The regex `[\^a]b` will match either `ab` or `^b`, so it should not match the string `'b'`.

Note that `re.match()` only matches at the beginning of a string, it is as if you have a beginning of string anchor at the beginning of your regex (`^` or `\A` with multiline option enabled).

So "to search for a 'b' that occurs either at start of line or followed by 'a'", you need to use `re.search()` with the following regex:

```
(^|a)b
```

Note that I am interpreting this slightly differently than the other answers, I *think* your requirement means that you want to match the 'b' in `'bob'` as well as the `ab` in `'taboo'`, so the start of line requirement is only for a `b` that is not preceeded by `a`.

This method of alternation in the group gives you a more scalable solution than `^b|ab`, so to match `b` at the start of the string or when preceeded by `a`, `x`, `2`, or `5` you could use the following:

```
(^|[ax25])b
```

Comment: Thank you! But can I use a `[]` character set to do so?

Comment: No, you cannot.  A character class always represents exactly one character, so you cannot put anchors into a character class.

Comment: See my edit, `(^|a)` should do what you expected your original character class to do.  (Use `(?:^|a)` if you don't want the capturing group)

Comment: Ahh ... that explains it. You should probably put in the explanation about ^ not being in the character set in the answer for future visitors. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Your first regex really means:

```
[\^a]b   # match a literal '^' or 'a', followed by a 'b'
```

Your second regex:

```
^b       # match start of line followed by a 'b'
```

What you really want for your first regex is:

```
^b|ab    # match start of line followed by a 'b', 
         # OR 
         # an 'a' followed by a 'b'
```

Also note `re.match()` automatically tries to find a match starting at the beginning, you want to use `re.search()` if you want to find strings that occur in the middle of the string.

> Say I want to search for a line start or 'a', or 'x', or '2' or '5' followed by a 'b'. Can't I do `[^ax25]b` instead of `^b|ab|xb|2b|5b`?

In that case, I would do:

```
(^|[ax25])b
```

The character class can only include, well, *characters*. The caret's (`^`) special meaning as a zero-width assertion matching the start of string changes when it's in a character class: it can negate the whole character class if its first character or mean the literal caret (`^`) if it's escaped or placed elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use a start of line inside `[]`? I want a solution that is *scalable*. Say I want to search for a line start or 'a', or 'x', or '2' or '5' followed by a 'b'. Can't I do `[^ax25]b` instead of `^b|ab|xb|2b|5b`?

Comment: I need to use a lookbehind, but lookbehinds have to be of definite length, so what do i do?