# Regex Python: Checking that the searched string contains at least 1 digit anywhere

Tags: python, regex

I need to get its article (model) from the product name.
The string I'm trying to get must start with a space or the beginning of the line, end with a space or the end of the line, **must contain at least 1 digit**. The string can also contain lowercase and uppercase letters, numbers, period, hyphen and slash.
I have already written part of the regular expression, but I cannot cope with the condition that the entire string must contain at least 1 digit. Please help me finish this check.
Here are some examples of input and expected output data:

1. input: "Odeon Light Foco 4722/4W Wall Lamp", output: "4722/4W"
2. input: "Thermostat LUZAR LT0532 - Luzar art. LT0532", output: "LT0532"
3. input: "Shock strut support in front of the right Febest FSS-TT9", output: "FSS-TT9"
   Initial version: r'(^|\s)[A-Za-z0-9-./]+($|\s)'

I have tried this option, but it does not always give the expected result
r'(^|\s)([\w-]+(\d+)[\w-]+)[A-Za-z0-9-./]+($|\s)'

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[^\s\d]*\d\S*', text)` ([demo](https://ideone.com/sqeGFO)) (or `re.search` to get the first match only).

Comment: Why not: `^\s?.*\d.*\s?$`?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following regex, as per your given data it outputs the required String

```
r"(^|\s)\S{0,}[0-9]{1,}\S?(\s|$)"
```

You can tweak `\S` as per your requirements.

Here is the Screenshot from regex101.com
[image]

UPDATE: I forgot your last case, here is updated version

Comment: You should really take a better look at regex docs, `[^|\s]` and `[\s|$]` are not doing what you think they do. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13199118/3832970), too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yea my mistake but () instead of [] will do the job

Comment: That will depend on the code.